# Airflow DeprecationWarning

Tags: airflow

I'm running a distributed Airflow 2.4.0 setup using the official Docker image. All the containers use the same `.env` file and same version of Airflow image. When I log into one of the Airflow containers I get this warning:

```
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545: DeprecationWarning: The sql_alchemy_conn option in [core] has been moved to the sql_alchemy_conn option in [database] - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:545: DeprecationWarning: The auth_backend option in [api] has been renamed to auth_backends - the old setting has been used, but please update your config.
  option = self._get_environment_variables(deprecated_key, deprecated_section, key, section)
/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/configuration.py:367: FutureWarning: The auth_backends setting in [api] has had airflow.api.auth.backend.session added in the running config, which is needed by the UI. Please update your config before Apache Airflow 3.0.
  FutureWarning,
```

I checked the `airflow.cfg` inside the container and it has the up to date variables. Why do I still get the warning messages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are seeing these warnings because of the section. `airflow.cfg` is configuration file with section. settings are expected to be in the proper section.

In your case your airflow.cfg has `sql_alchemy_conn` where you override the default value. Prior to 2.3.0 this setting in [core section](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/7c3513903462511212df742263a49ec1f729ec0e/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L31-L60) and in 2.3.0 it was moved to [database section](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/6b772f68db4f80b01ede836ddd47437d4aa1b43d/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L210-L215). (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22284))

What you need to do is simply open `airflow.cfg` and move the setting to the proper section. For example:

```
[core]

sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:///{AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.db
```

to:

```
[database]

sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:///{AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.db
```

The reason why it's like that is also explained in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#envvar-AIRFLOW__-SECTION-__-KEY). Airflow reference settings by environment variables of the format `AIRFLOW__{SECTION}__{KEY}` so in this case it will be:
`AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` so the section is important to find the variable.

Comment: It worked! I changed the variables in docker-compose .env and restarted the containers. What led me off at first, was that these variables were correctly set in the airflow.cfg inside the container. In fact, I thought that docker-compose will use the values to render the airflow.cfg file, but apparently something else happens.

Comment: `$docker exec -it docker_airflow-webserver_1 airflow config get-value api auth_backends
airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth,airflow.api.auth.backend.session`
AND

`$docker exec -it docker_airflow-webserver_1 cat airflow.cfg | grep auth_backends
auth_backends = airflow.api.auth.backend.session`